# strcmp da resultados inesperados

Tags: c, while

estaba practicando un poco de c para refrescar la memoria y hay unas lineas que no me estan funcionando:

```
int main(){

    char nombre[20];
    int cont = 3;

    printf("Ingresa tu nombre de usuario\n");
    fgets(nombre,20,stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    while(strcmp(nombre,"jorge")!=0){

        printf("Nombre de usuario incorrecto, ingrese nuevamente (Intentos restantes: %i)\n",cont);
        fgets(nombre,20,stdin);
        fflush(stdin);
        cont--;

    }


    if(cont==0) {
        printf("Se acabaron los intentos, vuelva mas tarde\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("El programa continua normalmente\n");
}
```

a pesar de que ponga el nombre valido (jorge) sigue entrando en el bucle y no entiendo porque

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguramente estas pasando el caracter de retorno (Enter) dentro de la cadena. Puedes solucionarlo ajustando strncmp a 5 letras "jorge":

```
strncmp(nombre,"jorge",5)!=0
```

o concatenando directamente el caracter de retorno CR ( \n ):

```
strcmp(nombre,"jorge\n")!=0
```

Comment: Que genio me sirvio gracias

Comment: Me temo que eso no sería una solución, si ingresa jorge1 no se lo debería tomar :l

Comment: sabes que si, como deberia hacer entonces? si le agrego un numero a "jorge" entra al bucle aunque no deberia

Comment: Eso es otro problema, pero si usas el segundo metodo deberia funcionar pefectamente.

Comment: si es cierto cardeol, la segunda solucion funciona perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Y si pruebas con esto?:

int main(){

```
char nombre[20];
int cont = 3;

printf("Ingresa tu nombre de usuario\n");
scanf("%s",nombre);
fflush(stdin);

while((strcmp(nombre,"jorge")!=0) && (cont>0)){

    printf("Nombre de usuario incorrecto, ingrese nuevamente (Intentos restantes: %i)\n",cont);
    scanf("%s",nombre);
    fflush(stdin);
    cont--;

}


if(cont==0) {
    printf("Se acabaron los intentos, vuelva mas tarde\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("El programa continua normalmente\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

En el while, agrego la condición de que los intentos sean mayores a 0.